# Order by columns in chain joined relations

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-order-by, relation

In my app I've got such models:

```python
class A(Base):
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    name_a = Column(Text)

class B(Base):
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    name_b = Column(Text)
    parent_a_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(A.id))
    parent_a = relationship(A, lazy='joined')

class C(Base):
    id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
    name_c = Column(Text)
    parent_b_id = Column(UUID, ForeignKey(B.id))
    parent_b = relationship(B, lazy='joined')
```

When I do:

```python
DBSession().query(C).all()
```

It works fine - I get all C names with it's B and A name in one LEFT OUTER JOIN query.

But I wonder how to **order by** this query with: **name_a, name_b, name_c**?

I'm trying to do something like:

```python
DBSession().query(C).order_by(
    C.parent_b.parent_a.name_a,
    C.parent_b.name_b,
    C.name_c
).all()
```

Such code doesn't work. How it can be done with sqlalchemy spirit?

Answer (score 2):

I played around with your sample and used PostgreSQL for added points.

Your query returns a list of C objects, and traditionally in SQL you can only sort by columns that you retrieve. The relations are retrieved behind the scenes so I don't see why it should be possible to sort by them.

On the bright side, once your list is retrieved it comes with the entire hierarchy in your memory, so you can sort it in memory super-fast:

```
clist = session.query(C).all()
sorted(clist, key=lambda c:(c.b.a.name, c.b.name, c.name))
```

Another solution I found is to use order_by `parameter` for `relationship`:

```
class B(Base):
   ...
   a = relationship(A, order_by="A.name", lazy='joined')

class C(Base):
   ...
   b = relationship(B, order_by="B.name", lazy='joined')
```

End result:

```
print (session.query(C).order_by(C.name) )
```

> ORDER BY tc.name, tb_1.name, ta_1.name

This is close to what you wanted but you will need to reverse the list to get it in the `A.name, B.name, C.name` order.

**P.S.:** my exact class definitions for reference:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine, Text
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

engine_connect_str = "postgresql://postgres@MYSERV/mydb"
engine = create_engine(engine_connect_str, echo=False)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
session = Session()
Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'ta'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(id={}, name='{}')".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.id, self.name)

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tb'    
    id = Column('id', Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    a_id = Column('aid', ForeignKey(A.id), nullable=False)

    a = relationship(A, order_by="A.name", lazy='joined')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(id={}, name='{}', a_id={})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.id, self.name, self.a_id)

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tc'    
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    b_id = Column('bid', ForeignKey(B.id), nullable=False)

    b = relationship(B, order_by="B.name", lazy='joined')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}(id={}, name='{}', b_id={})".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.id, self.name, self.b_id)
```

Comment: @vac I replaced the not working suggestion with a working one. The above comment no longer applies. New code has been tested.